# Drillthrough action displays only key attributes

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I have an SSAS 2016 cube in which I defined Drillthrough action for the Main measure group (the only measure group). 
I would like to display all regular attributes of a dimension in the Drillthrough so set it accordingly on the Action screen. 
The design has been deployed and the cube reprocessed with ProcessFull option.

When using the drillthrough, Excel displays the key attribute of each dimension leaving out all those configured but of the regular type.

I have not managed to find a config setting on the server or on the cube that would enable/disable/limit this feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out and thought I'd leave an answer to my question in case anyone else bumps into this issue.

When I double click a Pivot table measure number in Excel and details show, it is not the drill through action that shows the data but some builtin mechanism.

The drill through action - when configured and available - can be reached from the pivot table's measure area right click menu.